# Trouble with including external directories in C++ with ViconDataStreamSDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

#include "DataStreamClient.h" //[x]
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace ViconDataStreamSDK::CPP;
{ ...
```

This is the start of my file that uses the header file ViconDatastreamSDK.h but in every instance that a class from the file is called Visual Studio gives the error:

```
'ViconDataStreamSDK': is not a class or namespace name
```

The [solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfiR2.png) shows that the file is included in the external directories.

How do I get VisualStudio to recognize these classes?

Comment: Perhaps it needs an `#include "ViconDatastreamSDK.h"`?

Comment: I have that library saved under "DataStreamClient.h".  In that header file it defines
     namespace ViconDataStreamSDK {...}

Comment: At this point, I would double and triple check that the spelling in matches in both files.  It could also be that `ViconDataStreamSDK` is defined in some other namespace instead of the global namespace.